# Appium Inspector ion-input ID not appearing

Tags: ionic-framework, appium

I'm currently in the process of adding IDs to missing elements in our hybrid mobile app that is ionic and Cordova. But for some reason when I have the Id added when I go and view it in the Appium element inspector it doesn't appear. This has been the same process for our buttons and it has worked flawlessly but for some reason on edit text boxes it doesn't like it?

ion-input code:

[image]

Appium Element Inspector:

[image]

Button Example in code:

[image]

Comment: Post code, not images of it